# Can we change and customize pass key text in bluetooth dialog in android?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I want to change the passkey text **(Try 0000 and 1234)** in Ble Pairing dialog. Can we do it? Please check the attached image:

[Changed the text in rounded circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9XAD.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

thats system dialog, you can't change its text, this would be kind-of insecure for user... maybe use `Toast` for informing user about well-known PIN number